# Cannot resolve symbol 'gms'. Cannot import Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have tried everything given in other answers but still cannot import `gms`. Unlike other answers where error is in importing sub-classes of `gms` I am having trouble on gms itself.

This is the error I am getting
[image: Error]

EDIT: even if written like this
[image]

Added `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`
[image: Gradle]

This is what I have installed in SDK
[image: SDK]
[image: SDK External]

This is the project structure
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You probably don't need all the play services, so it is recommended to selectively pick the ones you really need to reduce your app size.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Comment: And I'm not sure where you found that is the package to import, but the first search for "android gms location" brings this  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.*;
```